# Полиморфизм в c#

Tags: c#, ооп

> *Из википедии:*
>
> Параметрический полиморфизм позволяет определять функцию или тип
> данных обобщённо, так что значения обрабатываются идентично вне
> зависимости от их типа.

В C# параметрический полиморфизм реализуется с помощью generic'ов или нет? Может кто объяснить?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, вы правы. Дженерики -- один из механизмов параметрического полиморфизма в C#. Например, вам нужно вывести число элементов коллекции. Все, что вам нужно от параметра функции -- свойство `Count`. При этом фактический тип параметра неважен. Соответственно вы можете написать этот метод так:

```
void PrintCountGeneric<T>(T collection) where T : ICollection
{
    Console.WriteLine(collection.Count);
}

...

var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
PrintCountGeneric(list);
```

Еще есть вариант без использования дженериков:

```
void PrintCount(ICollection collection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(collection.Count);
}

...

var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
PrintCount(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Примером может послужить ковариантность generic'ов. Взять хотя бы коллекцию `List<T>` и интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>` который она реализует. Благодаря параметрическому полиморфизму возможно такое неявное приведение типов : `IEnumerable<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();`

Другим примером может быть generic метод, которые возвращает "то, что принимает", его сигнатурой может быть что-то вроде :

```
T MyMethod<T>(T value);
```

Тип возвращаемых данных будет изменяться каждый раз при передаче экземпляра...